# Get Current Tab URL

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I am trying to pull the URL for whatever record the user is on when they launch my screenflow.

For example if they are on an account I would need the account URL: "https://mydomain--partial.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Account/00000000000000/view"

If they are on a report, I would need the report URL: "https://mydomain--partial.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Report/00000000000000000/view?queryScope=userFolders"

I am calling my flow in an Aura CMP and pulling the URL there. The Aura CMP is in a utility action.

I am able to get the URL, but it does not change when the users goes to a new tab. It will only change if the user refreshes the page.

I can't seem to find a way to see the change within the utility action.

Below is the code.

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction,lightning:isUrlAddressable" access="global" >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
    <lightning:flow aura:id="Requests"/>
    </aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
  init : function (cmp) {
    var vURL = window.location.href;
    var flow = cmp.find("Requests");
     var inputVariables = [
        {
            name : 'vCurentlURL',
            type : 'String',
            value : vURL,
        }
     ];
    flow.startFlow("Requests", inputVariables );
  }
})
```

Comment: what exactly is your end goal? why do you need to listen to tab changes using the URL ?

Comment: Well the overall purpose of the flow is to create a request record.  There is a category of requests = "other". When "other" is selected in the process the end-users want whatever page they are on captured. I figured the best way to do this was to get the URL. 

The above code works partially. Let's say I log into the org and open a report, the above code would only capture my homepage and not the url for the report. To get the url of the report I would have to manually refresh and then open the utility action again.